# Update a table with the most current information from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have two tables that are related by an employee ID

```
T1 (
    DateOfLatestChange,
    EmployeeID
)

T2 (
    EmployeeID,
    DateOfChange,
    CommentsOfChange
)
```

T2 will update frequently and I want T1 to hold the DateOfChange values of the latest value. I am looking to do this in a stored procedure without passing the EmployeeID parameters.

What is the best way to update this table?

Comment: Would it be feasible to pass a date parameter to your stored procedure as the starting point for comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be as simple as

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.DateOfChange = t2.DateOfChange
FROM t1 AS t1
JOIN (SELECT
  EmployeeID, max (DateOfChange) DateOfChange
FROM t2
GROUP BY EmployeeID) AS t2
  ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
```